# How to change button color into red (primary color to red color) after clicking button?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6

```css
.myClass{
    color : red;
  }
```

I need to change button color into red (primary color to red color) after clicking button, but it is change color of all buttons in a row but I need only selected button to change color.

```html
<tr*ngFor="let data of database ">
<td>{{data.name}}</td>
<td>{{data.id}}</td>
<td>
  <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="isClicked = !isClicked"  [class.myClass]="isClicked">
 <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
  <tr>
```

Comment: How many button do you have in row ?

Comment: actually i am getting data from Api  i have called first 2 columns from api in table and next columns  having maticon button which i called normally without api now these columns will also print according to api that means how many rows ( i mean how much data in api) these reaming  columns also print like that. in API i have 25 rows of data

Comment: you'll have to be either more specific on the classes that you use OR use a directive (but you'll have to define the style in that directive and not within the css file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isClicked property should be part of data object. dynamic classes can be added to the DOM using ngClass attribute.

```
.myClass{
   color : red !important;
}

<tr*ngFor="let data of database ">
<td>{{data.name}}</td>
<td>{{data.id}}</td>
<td>
  <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="data.isClicked = !data.isClicked"  [ngClass]="{'myClass': data.isClicked}">
 <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
  <tr>
```

Comment: no i cannot add data to isclicked because data is from API and button i had given normally

Comment: You want click state for all data items or a particular row?. For each row, you need to add isClicked property into API data response using forEach Loop.

Comment: i want click state for single button in row, but even i am clicking one button in row it is changing color of all buttons in a row

Comment: thank @suresh i got some idea  based on your answer and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

instead of declare field isClicked as boolean type, you should declare it as an object isClicked = {}. And this should be set for each row according to data.id

```
 <tr *ngFor="let data of database ">
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
    <td>
      <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="isClicked[data.id] = !isClicked[data.id]"  [class.myClass]="isClicked[data.id]">
     <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set isClicked as an array in your component class:
   isClicked: Array= [];

And declare a variable i in your template

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of database, let i = index ">
<td>{{data.name}}</td>
<td>{{data.id}}</td>
<td>
    <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="isClicked[i] = !isClicked[i]" 
      [class.myClass]="isClicked[i]">test
    </button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for your red button,

```
<button class="btn btn-danger"></button> or
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger"></button>
```

Comment: This assumes the user is using Bootstrap with default colour theme. There’s no suggestion of that in the question.